# Hadoop Port: fs.default.name

Tags: scala, hadoop

I am a bit confused. Pretty much every Hadoop installation "How to" I saw specified  `core-site.xml` sets `fs.default.name` to 9000

```
<configuration>
        <property>
            <name>fs.default.name</name>
            <value>hdfs://192.168.0.141:9000</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

However, the code below

```
val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://192.168.0.141/"), conf)
```

gave me a `java.net.ConnectException:` specifying unable to connect to port 8020.
I switched fs.default.name to port 8020 and now I seem to be up and running.

Can anyone suggest where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the default port, you must specify it

```
hdfs://192.168.0.141:9000/
```

Or you could put the core-site.xml on your Scala classpath, then by making `new Configuration()`, it'll load the address automatically for you during `FileSystem.get(conf)`

By the way, that property is deprecated in favor of `fs.defaultFS`